# Sharing a text file with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm attempting to share a text file with a UIActivityViewController. I'm creating and writing to my file in my app, and then allowing the user to share this file using whatever means they would like.

Currently I can access the file like this:

```
let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let objectsToShare = [text2]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Which works well, but it shares a long string of the contents of the file. Instead, I would like to share the file itself. How can I do this with Swift?

Answer (score 17):

After a little more searching I came up with the solution, turns out that instead of the actual file, I should have been trying to share the URL. I replaced

```
let text2 = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

with

```
let activityItem:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
```

and it works as expected!

Comment: How was activityItem passed along?

Comment: let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItem], applicationActivities: nil)